# WCF Service Applcation remaining idle until hit manually .svc file

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, python-idle

I create a WCF Service Application that runs in IIS 7.0 . In its initialization I start an endless loop ( while(true) ) , but after a period of time ,where I didn't call a method from his svc file, the wcf pass in an idle mode, and it doesn't react in the process the loop has to do. It is like it stops working. And then if i call a method to his svc file then starts working again. Is there a solution to avoid the idle mode so it can continue to keep the procedure in the loop alive?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The whole idea is that the process isn't active until called. What is the while (true) loop doing?

Answer (score 1):

WCF services are designed to "wake up" when requests are made.

If what you want is something like continuous polling, you may want to consider creating a [Windows Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service) instead.

If you're looking for a WCF service that maintains state, you'll have to implement that yourself. One way is to deploy a Workflow Service (using [WF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Workflow_Foundation) 4) with persistence, such as SqlWorkflowInstanceStore. It exposes its interface using WCF. The service will be idle between calls, but instances will remember state.

Answer (score 0):

WCF is meant to be consumed and to fire events, not to host long-running processes. You really want WF (workflow foundation) or BizTalk to host some long-running events. WCF events are typically short lived. You can create a XAMLX which combines the two concepts.